# Luatorrent compiling errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, boost, lua

I'm trying to build [Luatorrent](http://luatorrent.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/), a Lua module, it's quite old and really I just wanted to add one or two unfinished items to it but I can't get it to compile at all.

I'm using 'vintage' tools so I've got VS 2008 and boost 1.35.0.

I have added utils.h to the Header Files and torrent_session.cpp, torrent_info.cpp, torrent_handle.cpp and main.cpp to Source Files.

The following Pre-Processor Defines are added:

```
WIN32
_WINDOWS;
_USRDLL
WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
_WIN32_WINNT=0x0500
BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB
_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64
BOOST_THREAD_USE_LIB
UNICODE
TORRENT_USE_OPENSSL
NDEBUG
```

The following Additional Dependencies are compiled, without error, and added:

```
libboost_system-vc90-mt-1_35.lib
libboost_filesystem-vc90-mt-1_35.lib
libboost_date_time-vc90-mt-1_35.lib
libboost_thread-vc90-mt-1_35.lib
lua51.lib
libeay32.lib
ssleay32.lib
```

The following Additional Include Header Files are added:

```
C:\Client\boost-1_35_0\
C:\Client\libtorrent\include\
C:\Client\libtorrent\include\libtorrent\
C:\Client\libtorrent\zlib\
C:\Client\OpenSSL\include\
```

PCH support is disabled and according to the ReadMe with that done it should compile without errors but it never instead it threw 12 errors and 17 warnings, as far as I can tell the warnings are OK to ignore but the errors are what I need help with, here is the log:

```
 1>------ Build started: Project: Client, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
 1>Compiling...
 1>torrent_session.cpp
 1>C:\Client\libtorrent-0.12\include\libtorrent/session.hpp(86) : warning C4535: calling _set_se_translator() requires /EHa
 1>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Client\Client Source\torrent_session.cpp(107) : error C2664: 'libtorrent::torrent_handle libtorrent::session::add_torrent(const libtorrent::torrent_info &,const boost::filesystem::path &,const libtorrent::entry &,bool,int)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'boost::intrusive_ptr<T>' to 'const libtorrent::torrent_info &'
 1>        with
 1>        [
 1>            T=libtorrent::torrent_info
 1>        ]
 1>        Reason: cannot convert from 'boost::intrusive_ptr<T>' to 'const libtorrent::torrent_info'
 1>        with
 1>        [
 1>            T=libtorrent::torrent_info
 1>        ]
 1>        No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
 1>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Client\Client Source\torrent_session.cpp(109) : error C2664: 'libtorrent::torrent_handle libtorrent::session::add_torrent(const libtorrent::torrent_info &,const boost::filesystem::path &,const libtorrent::entry &,bool,int)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'boost::intrusive_ptr<T>' to 'const libtorrent::torrent_info &'
 1>        with
 1>        [
 1>            T=libtorrent::torrent_info
 1>        ]
 1>        Reason: cannot convert from 'boost::intrusive_ptr<T>' to 'const libtorrent::torrent_info'
 1>        with
 1>        [
 1>            T=libtorrent::torrent_info
 1>        ]
 1>        No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
 1>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Client\Client Source\torrent_session.cpp(112) : error C2664: 'libtorrent::torrent_handle libtorrent::session::add_torrent(const libtorrent::torrent_info &,const boost::filesystem::path &,const libtorrent::entry &,bool,int)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'boost::intrusive_ptr<T>' to 'const libtorrent::torrent_info &'
 1>        with
 1>        [
 1>            T=libtorrent::torrent_info
 1>        ]
 1>        Reason: cannot convert from 'boost::intrusive_ptr<T>' to 'const libtorrent::torrent_info'
 1>        with
 1>        [
 1>            T=libtorrent::torrent_info
 1>        ]
 1>        No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
 1>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Client\Client Source\torrent_session.cpp(180) : warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'libtorrent::size_type' to 'lua_Integer', possible loss of data
 1>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Client\Client Source\torrent_session.cpp(181) : warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'libtorrent::size_type' to 'lua_Integer', possible loss of data
 1>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Client\Client Source\torrent_session.cpp(182) : warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'libtorrent::size_type' to 'lua_Integer', possible loss of data
 1>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Client\Client Source\torrent_session.cpp(183) : warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'libtorrent::size_type' to 'lua_Integer', possible loss of data
 1>torrent_handle.cpp
 1>C:\Client\libtorrent-0.12\include\libtorrent/session.hpp(86) : warning C4535: calling _set_se_translator() requires /EHa
 1>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Client\Client Source\torrent_handle.cpp(52) : warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'libtorrent::size_type' to 'lua_Number', possible loss of data
 1>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Client\Client Source\torrent_handle.cpp(53) : warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'libtorrent::size_type' to 'lua_Number', possible loss of data
 1>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Client\Client Source\torrent_handle.cpp(54) : warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'libtorrent::size_type' to 'lua_Integer', possible loss of data
 1>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Client\Client Source\torrent_handle.cpp(55) : warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'libtorrent::size_type' to 'lua_Integer', possible loss of data
 1>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Client\Client Source\torrent_handle.cpp(56) : warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'libtorrent::size_type' to 'lua_Number', possible loss of data
 1>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Client\Client Source\torrent_handle.cpp(57) : warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'libtorrent::size_type' to 'lua_Number', possible loss of data
 1>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Client\Client Source\torrent_handle.cpp(80) : warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'libtorrent::size_type' to 'lua_Integer', possible loss of data
 1>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Client\Client Source\torrent_handle.cpp(81) : warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'libtorrent::size_type' to 'lua_Integer', possible loss of data
 1>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Client\Client Source\torrent_handle.cpp(451) : warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'const libtorrent::size_type' to 'lua_Integer', possible loss of data
 1>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Client\Client Source\torrent_handle.cpp(452) : warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'const libtorrent::size_type' to 'lua_Integer', possible loss of data
 1>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Client\Client Source\torrent_handle.cpp(470) : warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'const libtorrent::size_type' to 'lua_Integer', possible loss of data
 1>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Client\Client Source\torrent_handle.cpp(479) : error C2039: 'peer_source_flags' : is not a member of 'libtorrent::peer_info'
 1>        C:\Client\libtorrent-0.12\include\libtorrent/peer_info.hpp(46) : see declaration of 'libtorrent::peer_info'
 1>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Client\Client Source\torrent_handle.cpp(537) : error C2039: 'upload_limit' : is not a member of 'libtorrent::torrent_handle'
 1>        C:\Client\libtorrent-0.12\include\libtorrent/torrent_handle.hpp(216) : see declaration of 'libtorrent::torrent_handle'
 1>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Client\Client Source\torrent_handle.cpp(552) : error C2039: 'download_limit' : is not a member of 'libtorrent::torrent_handle'
 1>        C:\Client\libtorrent-0.12\include\libtorrent/torrent_handle.hpp(216) : see declaration of 'libtorrent::torrent_handle'
 1>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Client\Client Source\torrent_handle.cpp(575) : error C2039: 'piece_priority' : is not a member of 'libtorrent::torrent_handle'
 1>        C:\Client\libtorrent-0.12\include\libtorrent/torrent_handle.hpp(216) : see declaration of 'libtorrent::torrent_handle'
 1>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Client\Client Source\torrent_handle.cpp(577) : error C2039: 'piece_priority' : is not a member of 'libtorrent::torrent_handle'
 1>        C:\Client\libtorrent-0.12\include\libtorrent/torrent_handle.hpp(216) : see declaration of 'libtorrent::torrent_handle'
 1>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Client\Client Source\torrent_handle.cpp(608) : error C2039: 'prioritize_pieces' : is not a member of 'libtorrent::torrent_handle'
 1>        C:\Client\libtorrent-0.12\include\libtorrent/torrent_handle.hpp(216) : see declaration of 'libtorrent::torrent_handle'
 1>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Client\Client Source\torrent_handle.cpp(624) : error C2039: 'piece_priorities' : is not a member of 'libtorrent::torrent_handle'
 1>        C:\Client\libtorrent-0.12\include\libtorrent/torrent_handle.hpp(216) : see declaration of 'libtorrent::torrent_handle'
 1>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Client\Client Source\torrent_handle.cpp(659) : error C2039: 'prioritize_files' : is not a member of 'libtorrent::torrent_handle'
 1>        C:\Client\libtorrent-0.12\include\libtorrent/torrent_handle.hpp(216) : see declaration of 'libtorrent::torrent_handle'
 1>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Client\Client Source\torrent_handle.cpp(674) : error C2039: 'scrape_tracker' : is not a member of 'libtorrent::torrent_handle'
 1>        C:\Client\libtorrent-0.12\include\libtorrent/torrent_handle.hpp(216) : see declaration of 'libtorrent::torrent_handle'
 1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Client\Client\Release\BuildLog.htm"
 1>Client - 12 error(s), 17 warning(s)
 ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Error 1 references this [th = s->add_torrent(t, path, e)], error 2 and 3 are the same error code:

```
static int torrent_session_add_torrent(lua_State *L) {
 int n = lua_gettop(L);
 void* ud = 0;

 ud = luaL_checkudata(L, 1, "Torrent.Session");
 session *s = *((session **)ud);

 ud = luaL_checkudata(L, 2, "Torrent.Info");
 torrent_info *ti = *((torrent_info **)ud);

 boost::intrusive_ptr<torrent_info> t(ti);

 try {
torrent_handle th;

if (n >= 3 && !lua_isnil(L, 3)) {
    const char *path = "./";

    if (!lua_isnil(L, 3)) {
    path = luaL_checkstring(L, 3);
    }

    if (n == 4 && !lua_isnil(L, 4)) {
    const char *filename = luaL_checkstring(L, 4);

    std::ifstream in(filename, std::ios_base::binary);
    in.unsetf(std::ios_base::skipws);

    entry e = bdecode(std::istream_iterator<char>(in), std::istream_iterator<char>());

    th = s->add_torrent(t, path, e);
    } else {
    th = s->add_torrent(t, path);
    }
} else {
    th = s->add_torrent(t, "./");
}

torrent_handle **h = (torrent_handle **)lua_newuserdata(L, sizeof(torrent_handle *));
*h = new torrent_handle(th);

luaL_getmetatable(L, "Torrent.Handle");
lua_setmetatable(L, -2);
 } catch (std::exception& e) {
luaL_error(L, "%s", e.what());
lua_pushnil(L);
 }

 return 1;
}
```

All the other errors reference this in torrent_handle.cpp where its believed the returned table items are not a member of 'libtorrent::torrent_handle':

```
static int torrent_handle_get_peer_info(lua_State *L) {
 void* ud = 0;

 ud = luaL_checkudata(L, 1, "Torrent.Handle");
 torrent_handle *h = *((torrent_handle **)ud);

 std::vector<peer_info> peers;

 h->get_peer_info(peers);

 int c = 1;
 lua_newtable(L);
 for (std::vector<peer_info>::const_iterator i = peers.begin(); i != peers.end(); ++i) {
    lua_pushinteger(L, c);

    lua_newtable(L);
    LUA_PUSH_ATTRIB_INT("flags", i->flags);

std::ostringstream out;
out << i->ip;
LUA_PUSH_ATTRIB_STRING("ip", out.str().c_str());

    LUA_PUSH_ATTRIB_FLOAT("up_speed", i->up_speed);
    LUA_PUSH_ATTRIB_FLOAT("down_speed", i->down_speed);
    LUA_PUSH_ATTRIB_FLOAT("payload_up_speed", i->payload_up_speed);
    LUA_PUSH_ATTRIB_FLOAT("payload_down_speed", i->payload_down_speed);
    LUA_PUSH_ATTRIB_INT("total_download", i->total_download);
    LUA_PUSH_ATTRIB_INT("total_upload", i->total_upload);
//pid
//pieces

std::vector<bool> pieces = i->pieces;
lua_pushstring(L, "pieces");
lua_newtable(L);
int d = 1;
for (std::vector<bool>::const_iterator b = pieces.begin(); b != pieces.end(); ++b) {
    LUA_PUSH_ARRAY_BOOL(d, *b);
}   

lua_settable(L, -3);

LUA_PUSH_ATTRIB_BOOL("seed", i->seed);
    LUA_PUSH_ATTRIB_INT("upload_limit", i->upload_limit);
    LUA_PUSH_ATTRIB_INT("download_limit", i->download_limit);
    LUA_PUSH_ATTRIB_STRING("country", i->country);
    LUA_PUSH_ATTRIB_INT("load_balancing", i->load_balancing);
    LUA_PUSH_ATTRIB_INT("download_queue_length", i->download_queue_length);
    LUA_PUSH_ATTRIB_INT("upload_queue_length", i->upload_queue_length);
    LUA_PUSH_ATTRIB_INT("downloading_piece_index", i->downloading_piece_index);
    LUA_PUSH_ATTRIB_INT("downloading_block_index", i->downloading_block_index);
    LUA_PUSH_ATTRIB_INT("downloading_progress", i->downloading_progress);
    LUA_PUSH_ATTRIB_INT("downloading_total", i->downloading_total);
    LUA_PUSH_ATTRIB_STRING("client", i->client.c_str());
    LUA_PUSH_ATTRIB_INT("connection_type", i->connection_type);
    LUA_PUSH_ATTRIB_INT("peer_source_flags", i->peer_source_flags);
    lua_settable(L, -3);

    c++;
 }

 return 1;
}
```

I have a precomputed dll so I know the code does work but obviously without being able to rebuild it I cant add the extra features I need.